# adding a set time to any date in php

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

basically what I need to do is add the time 00:01 to any date that has been selected by the user to find results between the date/times, can anyone help me out?

Comment: What is the format of the `date that has been selected by the user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a timestamp for 00:01 on a date like so:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($date_from_user . ' 00:01');
```

You can then format that timestamp as desired using `date()`, though you probably don't need to do that.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE datecol BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'
```

Comment: wow that was fast! didn't know you could concatenate the time onto dates like that, thanks for the answer n quick response!! hope you have a nice day :D